# VB MySql AddWithValue doesn't pass the value successfully

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following VB code

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT code FROM decoder WHERE ann_id = @aid", conn) 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aid", 1)

Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

The reader.Read() then gives me nothing, however, if I replace the code by

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT code FROM decoder WHERE ann_id = 1", conn) 

Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

reader.Read() gives the correct result. Tried using Add instead, doesn't help. What am I  missing here?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

remove `@`

```
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT code FROM decoder WHERE ann_id = @aid", conn) 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("aid", 1)
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ButtonInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonInsert.Click
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand

    conn.ConnectionString = Me.Tag.ToString

    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NULL, @number, @text)"
        cmd.Prepare()

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", 1) 'sets @number to be numeric
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "One") 'sets @text to be characters

        For i = 1 To 1000

            cmd.Parameters("@number").Value = i
            cmd.Parameters("@text").Value = "A string value"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Error " & ex.Number & " has occurred: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```